# Print character in a for loop c++

Tags: c++, char, string-literals

This is a pretty basic question as I am new to the C++ language but I have a program that takes a function to print a single character in a for loop. My code is shown below:

```
void printBar(const char symbol, int count){
    for (int i = 0;i <= count; i++){
        cout << symbol;
    }
}
```

and my main function is this:

```
int main(){
    int size = 8;
    const char* sym = "*":
    printBar(sym,size);
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
********
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: s/`printBar(sym,size);`/`printBar(*sym,size);`

Comment: `char*` and `char` are different types.

Comment: You are passing a *pointer* to a character, not a single character.  Try `printBar(sym[0], size);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should say what goes wriong. Errors, wrong output.... But I can guess

First this loop is wrong

```
void printBar(const char symbol, int count){
    for (int i = 0;i <= count; i++){
        cout << symbol;
    }
}
```

it will print one too many char. You should have `i < count`

Second your function needs a char, but you pass in a char*

Do this

```
int main(){

int size = 8;
const char sym = '*':
printBar(sym,size);
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters there is a typo

```
const char* sym = "*":
                    ^^^
```

There shall be a semicolon.

The loop in the function should look like

```
void printBar(const char symbol, int count){
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                    ^^^^^^^^^
        cout << symbol;
    }
}
```

And the qualifier const in the first parameter declaration may be removed.

```
void printBar(char symbol, int count){
```

If the variable `sym` declared like

```
const char* sym = "*":
```

then the function should be called like

```
printBar(*sym,size);
```

or

```
printBar(sym[0],size);
```

that is you need to pass to the function just one character instead of the pointer.

Another approach to write the function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::ostream & printBar( char symbol, size_t count, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    if ( count )
    {
        os << std::setw( count ) << std::setfill( symbol ) << symbol; 
    }

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    size_t size = 8;
    const char *sym = "*";

    printBar( *sym, size ) << std::endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
********
```

Comment: why remove `const`? It doesnt hurt, or am I missing something?

Comment: @tobi303 The argument is passed to the function by value. So the qualifier does not make great sense. These two function declarations void printBar( condt char symbol, int count); and void printBar(char symbol, int count); declare the same one function.

Comment: It expresses that the parameter is not modified inside the function. Whether this makes sense is a matter of taste, I can understand your point of view. Btw I was really just confused for a second, but of course it does not make much difference concerning correctness

Comment: @tobi303 If in the function definition you will declare the parameter with the qualifier const then indeed within the function you may not change it. But this has nothing common with the original argument because the argument is passed to the function by value that is the function deals with a copy of the value of the argument. So for users of the function it is entirely unimportant whether the parameter that is a local variable of the function is changed or not within the function. The original argument in any case will be unchanged.

Comment: yes, sorry for starting a discussion on a non-issue. When thinking about it, I am also in favor of removing the `const` because it is an implementation detail and just leads to confusion (and unnecessary discussions ;)